# Any way to use a conversion function inside a hibernate restrictions method?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Currently I have a statement in my hibernate service like this:

```
  Criteria criteria =  
 session.createCriteria(PatientId.class).add(Restrictions.eq("acct",account_));
```

The problem with this is that the variable account_ is interpreted by MS SQL
 nvarchar (4000).   This can be avoided by using the CONVERT function and converting the unbounded String variable, account_ as follows: CONVERT(varchar(20),account).

This is all find and well if I was writing straight SQL code.  But I'm unsure of how to do this within hibernate except by rewriting my service as a SQLQuery.    Is there any way to use the existing Restrictions method in conjunction with the CONVERT function?